# How to check Phone number is valid or not like Email MX record

Tags: c#, validation

We can validate email id by checking MX record.

Like same way, is their any method that I can validate phone number are valid or not. Except Regx expression

Comment: First of all you should define what "valid number" means to you. Is it simply 10 digits preceeded by plus sign, or it should be checked against countries phone codes and so on?

Comment: You can only check, if a phone number _might_ be valid. But to verify it without doubt, you'd have to call it.

Comment: Ex: India number +91 9654284487. I want to check is this number is valid ? or Really Exist ?

Comment: @Grumbler85 please check this link http://api.phone-validator.net/

Comment: So, the answer is _"Yes, using an API"_, which you already found. What is your question?

Comment: @Chandan as I said - it _might_ be valid: If I enter my number into that API i get VALID_UNCONFIRMED, which essentially means Countryprefix and Regionprefix do exist.

Comment: My question is How can I achieve same thing. Like Email Id MX record, For Phone Number anything  ? Sorry If I am wrong

Comment: See CodeCasters comment - use that API or build an own database of all country and region codes and validate against that.

Comment: By the way - I shortened my phone number to three digit and the API made a false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MX-record will only tell you that the domain accepts email, not that an address actually exists or even that there is a mailserver configured at the specified IP.

The nearest you will get for phone numbers would be to check that the country code is valid and possibly that the region code exists within that country. If you need better validation then that, you would have to either call the user or have them call you and use caller id to see that the number is valid.